# python tuple of ids of integers or lists

Tags: python-3.3

In Python 3.3 for Windows, every list gets a different id when it is created:

```
>>> id([3])
46555784
>>> id([3])
47920192
>>> id([4])
46532048
```

But if I write a tuple asking for the ids of two lists, each list seems to get the same id:

```
>>> id([3]), id([4])
(43079000, 43079000)
```

I was expecting a tuple with two different ids. What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: All lists have the same `id` in both Python 2 and 3 on Linux (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

According to [Python 3.3 id Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#id) the id for CPython gives the memory address of the object.

When I tried doing the following:

```
print(id([3]))
print(id([4]))
print(id([5]))
print((id([3]), id([4])))
```

I got the same memory address for each of the lists.

However, if you do the following:

```
print(id([3]))
print(id([4]))
print(id([5]))
i = [3]
j = [4]
print((id(i), id(j)))
```

The first 3 print statements and the first id of the tuple were the same but the second id in the tuple was different. Which makes sense because two different objects are created and assigned *then* the ids are retrieved.

But these were in a python script not in interactive mode as your post suggests. However, I got effectively the same results the in the interactive mode.

So, to answer your question, it *appears* that the interpreter is allocating the arrays to different locations between calls. But when declaring the tuple it seems to allocate, get the id, free, allocate, get the id and free and it happens to be the same location.

I was echo'ing Blender's comment where I would get all the same id results if I did not declare an array or if there were no nested arrays.

When I tried something like this:

```
print(id([3]), id([3]))
print(id([3]), id([3,[3]]))
```

The first print statement ids had the same id result but the second print statement ids were different but one of the ids shared the same id as the first print statement.